# Json Template Validation error with Split Function

Tags: json, azure

I am getting below error while doing deployment through Visual studio Team services.

"The template language function 'split' expects its first parameter to be of type 'String'. The provided value is of type 'Uri"

Points:-
1.I am using linked templates. 
2.I am sending "linked template URL" to the split function.

The things were working just fine until today.
Now the issue is there.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards
RatZ

Answer (score 0):

it might be a temporary thing, i saw a thread somewhere about deployment.uri functions is broken. that being said try casting your uri to string explicitly:

```
split(string(bla-bla-bla), ...)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it was an issue with deployment function as mentioned by you.